# Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined] NODE.JS + SQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I would like to separate the router.get () from queries from sql queries, but I had this error, when I declare the direct function as parameter of router.get () function it works.

**User.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const database = require('../queries/userQueries');

router.get('/users',database.getAllUsers);

module.exports = router;
```

**userQueries.js**

```
function getAllUsers(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.connection.query('SELECT * from usuarios', 
    function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error){ 
            res.send(error); 
            return; 
        }
        res.send(results);
    });
};

module.exports = getAllUsers;
```

> Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
>           at Route.(anonymous function) [as get] (/home/antonio/achaiAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:202:15)
>           at Function.proto.(anonymous function) [as get] (/home/antonio/achaiAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:510:19)
>           at Object. (/home/antonio/achaiAPI/api/routes/user.js:11:8)
>           at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
>           at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
>           at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
>           at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
>           at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
>           at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
>           at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning the function `getAllUsers` itself to the `module.exports`, not to a *property* of `module.exports`. So, when you import it with `require`, that resolves to *said function*, not an object with that function as one of its properties.

Try assigning the imported object to a variable name representing the function instead:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const getAllUsers = require('../queries/userQueries');

router.get('/users', getAllUsers);

module.exports = router;
```

You would use

```
const database = require('../queries/userQueries');
router.get('/users',database.getAllUsers);
```

when your `userQueries.js` had assigned the function to a *property* of the `exports`:

```
module.exports.getAllUsers = function getAllUsers( ...
```

Comment: @AntonioSoares If exporting multiple functions in `userQueries.js`, then assign each function to a property of `exports` instead, and use your original code.

Answer (score 0):

getAllUsers is already a function，so you can Use directly.
change `router.get('/users',database.getAllUsers);` to `router.get('/users',database);`. you can yet return an object in `userQueries.js` file